# How can I hook a function in a python module?

Tags: python, module, package

I have a package in my virtual environment installed in the `site-packages` folder of it.
In that package there is a module with a bunch of functions. I want to change one of these functions without touching the package code, so I want to make a hook of that module and then change/overwrite the function so it behaves in the way I want.

I don't know if this is even possible in Python (I'm new to the language).

Example:

I have a package called their_package in my site-packages folder, inside I have a module named `whatever.py` with the following code:

```
import sys
import os

def this_is_a_function(parameter):
    //whatever logic in here
    return result
```

What I want is to hook the `whatever.py` module so I can redefine the `this_is_a_function` to have a different logic. Is this possible? I would appreciate a lot a code sample!

Comment: How do you plan to use that hooked module later?  Do you want to hook it only for one scenario (piece of logic), or for the whole Python interpreter session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine your function with:

```
import whatever

def this_is_a_function(parameter):
    pass

whatever.this_is_a_function = this_is_a_function
```

Comment: I don't understand where is “redefined the `this_is_a_function` to have a different logic” as asked by the OP.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé It runs `pass` instead of whatever the function did before. Obviously replace this with something more complex if that's what you want.