# Hook python module function

Tags: python

Basically I want to do something like this:
[How can I hook a function in a python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933287/how-can-i-hook-a-function-in-a-python-module)

but I want to call the old function after my own code.

like

```
import whatever

oldfunc = whatever.this_is_a_function

def this_is_a_function(parameter):
    #my own code here
    # and call original function back
    oldfunc(parameter)

whatever.this_is_a_function = this_is_a_function
```

Is this possible?

I tried `copy.copy`, `copy.deepcopy` original function but it didn't work.

Comment: It depends on what `whatever` is. What is it in this case? Is it your own module?

Comment: no it's not my own module, it is a module registered from C++ code by application I don't have source code for(I know I can hook function in C++ but I'm interested if it's possible straight from python)

Comment: The code you've posted looks fine, aside from perhaps `return oldfunc(parameter)` instead of just `oldfunc(parameter)`. Are you having a problem with it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this? It avoids using globals, which is generally a good thing.

```
import whatever
import functools

def prefix_function(function, prefunction):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def run(*args, **kwargs):
        prefunction(*args, **kwargs)
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return run

def this_is_a_function(parameter):
    pass # Your own code here that will be run before

whatever.this_is_a_function = prefix_function(
    whatever.this_is_a_function, this_is_a_function)
```

`prefix_function` is a function that takes two functions: `function` and `prefunction`. It returns a function that takes any parameters, and calls `prefunction` followed by `function` with the same parameters. The `prefix_function` function works for any callable, so you only need to program the prefixing code once for any other hooking you might need to do.

`@functools.wraps` makes it so that the docstring and name of the returned wrapper function is the same.

If you need `this_is_a_function` to call the old `whatever.this_is_a_function` with arguments different than what was passed to it, you could do something like this:

```
import whatever
import functools

def wrap_function(oldfunction, newfunction):
    @functools.wraps(oldfunction)
    def run(*args, **kwargs):
        return newfunction(oldfunction, *args, **kwargs)
    return run

def this_is_a_function(oldfunc, parameter):
    # Do some processing or something to customize the parameters to pass
    newparams = parameter * 2  # Example of a change to newparams
    return oldfunc(newparams)

whatever.this_is_a_function = wrap_function(
        whatever.this_is_a_function, this_is_a_function)
```

There is a problem that if `whatever` is a pure C module, it's typically impossible (or very difficult) to change its internals in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

So, here's an example of monkey-patching the `time` function from the `time` module.

```
import time

old_time = time.time

def time():
    print('It is today... but more specifically the time is:')
    return old_time()

time.time = time

print time.time()
# Output:
# It is today... but more specifically the time is:
# 1456954003.2
```

However, if you are trying to do this to C code, you will most likely get an error like `cannot overwrite attribute`. In that case, you probably want to subclass the C module.

You may want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705964/how-do-i-extend-a-python-module-python-twitter).

Answer (score 3):

This is the perfect time to tout my super-simplistic Hooker

```
def hook(hookfunc, oldfunc):
    def foo(*args, **kwargs):
        hookfunc(*args, **kwargs)
        return oldfunc(*args, **kwargs)
    return foo
```

Incredibly simple. It will return a function that first runs the desired hook function (with the same parameters, mind you) and will then run the original function that you are hooking and return that original value. This also works to overwrite a class method. Say we have static method in a class.

```
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def bar(data):
        for datum in data:
            print(datum, end="") # assuming python3 for this
        print()
```

But we want to print the length of the data before we print out its elements

```
def myNewFunction(data):
    print("The length is {}.".format(len(data)))
```

And now we simple hook the function

```
Foo.bar(["a", "b", "c"])
# => a b c
Foo.bar = hook(Foo.bar, myNewFunction)
Foo.bar(["x", "y", "z"])
# => The length is 3.
# => x y z
```

Comment: Why use `staticmethod` instead of just plain functions?

Comment: For the Hooker class, an instance variable is entirely unnecessary. I added an init function so it CAN be used, i.e. `h = Hooker()`, but it isn't necessary. If I don't use `@staticmethod`, then an instance would have had to have been declared.

Comment: No, no. Why does `Hooker` exist at all? Why is `hook` a static method of a `Hooker` class instead of just a module-level function?

Comment: @Goodies I suppose I meant "why encapsulate in a class at all"? Considering this is a utility function, I feel this would make most sense as a plain function in its own module, much like `functools.wraps`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, personally, I just have this sitting in my libs. From any file I can import Hooker. The file is called Hooker.py and there are no classes in it. yes, it is unnecessary.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around? `Foo.bar = hook(myNewFunction, Foo.bar)`.  foo returns `oldfunc`

Comment: Just to make sure, the final two outputs are reversed yes?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can replace the target function's `func_code`. The example below

```
# a normal function
def old_func():
    print "i am old"

# a class method
class A(object):
    def old_method(self):
        print "i am old_method"

# a closure function
def make_closure(freevar1, freevar2):
    def wrapper():
        print "i am old_clofunc, freevars:", freevar1, freevar2
    return wrapper
old_clofunc = make_closure('fv1', 'fv2')

# ===============================================

# the new function
def new_func(*args):
    print "i am new, args:", args
# the new closure function
def make_closure2(freevar1, freevar2):
    def wrapper():
        print "i am new_clofunc, freevars:", freevar1, freevar2
    return wrapper
new_clofunc = make_closure2('fv1', 'fv2')

# ===============================================

# hook normal function
old_func.func_code = new_func.func_code
# hook class method
A.old_method.im_func.func_code = new_func.func_code
# hook closure function
# Note: the closure function's `co_freevars` count should be equal
old_clofunc.func_code = new_clofunc.func_code

# ===============================================

# call the old
old_func()
A().old_method()
old_clofunc()
```

output:

```
i am new, args: ()
i am new, args: (<__main__.A object at 0x0000000004A5AC50>,)
i am new_clofunc, freevars: fv1 fv2
```